# MySQL DB displays question marks instead of letters in Hebrew

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, visual-studio-2017

I have been connecting to my Database on AWS using MySQL Workbench & my Visual Studio 2017 WPF application which uses that database,
and for some reason even when I create a table with UTF-8 or UTF-8 bin, It still displays values with question marks instead of Hebrew letters.
I had also tried NVARCHAR (with a len of 15) and it still didn't work for some reason :/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPoTO.png)

Please help :)
Thanks in advance, Have a great day!

Comment: What is the collation of the database?  Can you even enter Hebrew letters into your Workbench?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I can, for some reason I've seen just now that my comment back in the day wasn't posted..